# Separate columns in R based on the second occurence of ("\\.")

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a very hard to separate my columns from data set

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

tibble(sample=c("AM.F10.T1", "AM.F10.T2","DA.AD.1","DA.AD.2", "ES.AD.1"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   sample   
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 AM.F10.T1
#> 2 AM.F10.T2
#> 3 DA.AD.1  
#> 4 DA.AD.2  
#> 5 ES.AD.1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

and make them look like

```
#>   sample        col1      col2
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 AM.F10.T1     AM.F10     T1
#> 2 AM.F10.T2     AM.F10     T2
#> 3 DA.AD.1       DA.AD       1
#> 4 DA.AD.2       DA.AD       2
#> 5 ES.AD.1       ES.AD       1
```

Thank you for spending time in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `tidyr::separate_wider_regex()` (this function is in the recent release of `tidyr`). You can be explicit about what is in the first and second columns and what separates them.

```r
library(tidyr)
tibble(sample=c("AM.F10.T1", "AM.F10.T2","DA.AD.1","DA.AD.2", "ES.AD.1")) |> 
  separate_wider_regex(
     cols = sample, 
     patterns = c(first  = "\\w*\\.\\w*", "\\.", second = "\\w*")
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   first  second
#>   <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 AM.F10 T1    
#> 2 AM.F10 T2    
#> 3 DA.AD  1     
#> 4 DA.AD  2     
#> 5 ES.AD  1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thannk you for taking the time and teaching me and the community something new

Answer (score 1):

Although the `extract` function from the `tidyr` package was superseded by `separate_wider_regex`, I think it's still useful sometimes.

Using an aggressive match in the first capture group would force the latter capture group to get the content after the second dot.

```r
library(tidyr)

extract(df, sample, regex = "(.*)\\.(.*)", into = c("col1", "col2"), remove = F)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  sample    col1   col2 
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>
1 AM.F10.T1 AM.F10 T1   
2 AM.F10.T2 AM.F10 T2   
3 DA.AD.1   DA.AD  1    
4 DA.AD.2   DA.AD  2    
5 ES.AD.1   ES.AD  1
```